# Поле ввода с маской ММ/ГГ

Tags: java, android, инспекция-кода

Прошу покритиковать код  с примерами чем бы вы что заменили. Дан кусок кода и он касается только поля "срок действия"

Задача:

- если ввод начинается с числа(Х) больше 1 его автоматически модифицирует в 0Х,
- если первое число 1 второе не должно быть больше 2,
- после ввода первых двух чисел автоматически ставится символ "/" после него возможен ввод ещё двух чисел.
- Еще нужно чтобы можно было удалять числа в поле ввода.

```
 @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (mCountAfter > mCountBefore && mStartNumber == 0) {
                if(s.toString().equals("0")|s.toString().equals("1")){
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(s.toString());
                    editTextValidity.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    editTextValidity.setText("0" + s+"/");
                    editTextValidity.addTextChangedListener(this);
                    editTextValidity.setSelection(3);
                }
            }
            if (mCountAfter > mCountBefore && mStartNumber == 1) {
                if(s.toString().equals("01")|s.toString().equals("02")|s.toString().equals("03")|s.toString().equals("04")|s.toString().equals("05")|s.toString().equals("06")|s.toString().equals("07")|s.toString().equals("08")|s.toString().equals("09")|s.toString().equals("10")|s.toString().equals("11")|s.toString().equals("12")){
                    s.append("/");
                }
                else{
                    s.delete(s.length()-1, s.length());
                }

            } else if (mCountAfter < mCountBefore && mStartNumber == 2) {
                s.delete(s.length()-1, s.length());
            }

            if (s.length() == 6) {
                s.delete(s.length()-1, s.length());
                editTextCVV.requestFocus();

            }


        }
    });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я вам советую посмотреть в сторону библиотеки от тинькофф [decoro](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/decoro). написать свой слот со своей маской. У них хорошая вики на русском

Answer (score 0):

http://www.quizful.net/post/Java-RegExp

С помощью этого инструмента всё можно сделать, только нужно быть осторожным и проверять всё вот здесь :http://regexr.com/  .